# Lua Hammerspoon: hs.window.focusedWindow() is nil when assigned to a variable

Tags: macos, lua, hammerspoon

I use an automation software called [hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org/go/) on osx.

When I use the following code in hammerspoon's console, `win` is nil:

```
> local win = hs.window.focusedWindow()
> win
nil
```

But actually the function returns some value:

```
> hs.window.focusedWindow()
hs.window: Hammerspoon Console (0x60000025f798)
```

This strange behavior breaks all window moving/sizing functions such as:

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl"}, "H", function()
    local win = hs.window.focusedWindow()
    local f = win:frame()

    f.x = f.x - 10
    win:setFrame(f)
end)
```

Hammerspoon gives this error:

```
/Users/mertnuhoglu/.hammerspoon/init.lua:6: attempt to index a nil value (local 'win')
stack traceback:
    /Users/mertnuhoglu/.hammerspoon/init.lua:6: in function </Users/mertnuhoglu/.hammerspoon/init.lua:4>
stack traceback:
```

I don't know if this problem is caused by my computer or something else.

I have osx yosemite, version 10.10.5 and hammerspoon 0.9.43.

### Update:

I found solution of the error. It is due to Privacy settings of osx.

Solution:

```
Prefences > Security > Privacy > Allow Apps: Hammerspoon
```

But still, I don't understand why `hs.window.focusedWindow()` returns something if it is not assigned to a variable and it returns `nil` when it is assigned to a variable.

Comment: If that's the default lua repl (or similar) then drop `local`. Each line is executed in its own chunk so your `local` variable isn't in scope anymore for the next line.

Comment: Also don't solve your question with an update to the question itself. File an answer and, if you think it is the correct one and no one else answers, then accept it.

Comment: Thank you @EtanReisner, actually dropping `local` solved the unexpected behavior. I think this is the actual answer. Please file it as answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: That issue should not affect an actual script being run by the application itself in the normal way. That's an artifact of how the lua repl works. I don't know what permissions issue you say you fixed but that if that fixed the actual script then that's the solution to your *real* problem. The `local` issue at the repl is a side-issue to that issue .

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this?

Comment: My security settings do include the "allowance" of Hammerspoon.

The issue remains that for me, similar to yours, wherein the returning value is `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Hammerspoon executes each line as it's own chunk, so local variables are only available in that chunk, and no longer once the chunk has been executed.

If you want to access variables after execution of a chunk, make them global, i.e. drop the 'local' keyword.