# Why does hammerspoon return focused window nil when it should not?

Tags: macos, lua, hammerspoon

I was trying to use [hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org/) to control my windows (on MAC OSX) but was having some issue. Straight from the [getting started](http://www.hammerspoon.org/go/#winresize) page I copied the code for moving the focused window left:

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl"}, "Left", function()
  local win = hs.window.focusedWindow()
  local f = win:frame()
  local screen = win:screen()
  local max = screen:frame()

  f.x = max.x
  f.y = max.y
  f.w = max.w / 2
  f.h = max.h
  win:setFrame(f)
end)
```

I then when back reloaded my config and tried it out. Unfortunately, it doesn't work and opens the hammerspoon console with the following error:

```
*** ERROR: hs.hotkey callback error: /Users/my_secret_username/.hammerspoon/init.lua:25: attempt to index a nil value (local 'win')
stack traceback:
    /Users/my_secret_username/.hammerspoon/init.lua:25: in function </Users/my_secret_username/.hammerspoon/init.lua:23>
```

it says that my variable is nil but I don't see why it should be nil. I tried inserting a (what I assume in hammerspoon is) a print statement `hs.console.printStyledtext(win)` right after the variable win to inspect it but that also throws the same error except it print `nil` right before the error.

The strange thing is that the functionality or the code "works" (i.e. moves m screen left) once it focuses on the console but nothing else that I have tried.

Has anyone seen this type of bug and been able to fix it?

---

I did see:

[Lua Hammerspoon: hs.window.focusedWindow() is nil when assigned to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743870/lua-hammerspoon-hs-window-focusedwindow-is-nil-when-assigned-to-a-variable)

and it seems that changing the variables from local to global makes no difference and the bug persists.

Comment: What do you mean it "works" "once it focuses on the console"? Do you mean it works when you have a window focused but doesn't otherwise? Does that privacy setting bit help any?

Comment: @EtanReisner it works as in it moves the console around the screen as it should, though it only moves it around as it should iff I am focused on the console screen.

Comment: @EtanReisner it seems updating my OS X to the most recent OS fixed this bug. Such a trivial solution, not sure if there might be anything else wrong but so far so good.

Comment: If there isn't a focused window then you can't expect `hs.window.focusedWindow()` to return anything. So it returning `nil` in that case makes perfect sense.

Comment: @EtanReisner but there **was** a focused window.

Comment: Then I didn't understand your comment about the console window. Are you saying that when you focus the hammerspoon console window it moves some *other* window? But that if you have the other window focused nothing moves and you get the `nil` error?

Comment: @EtanReisner sorry. What I meant to say exactly was, that it only moves the windows around when I focused on the cosole window. If I focus on any other window it would open the console window without me asking it to do so and display an error message.

Comment: Ah, ok. That sounds like the accessibility feature not being allowed for hammerspoon then I think (there's a FAQ about that I believe). But if an upgrade got it working who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that it might have been a incompatibility of the OS I had. Make sure to have the latest OS X and hammerspoon software.

Comment: This solved my issue. I don't know why I received a downvote. If its not explained I will delete the question

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and was solved by granting "Accessibility" permissions to Hammerspoon in the "Security & Privacy" panel in OSX System Preferences.